# SwiftUI enum with custom rawValue

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm querying an API and I'm retrieving some values that I code into JSON.
One of the attributes is `job_type` whose value I know that could only take some finite range of values, so I've written:

```
enum JobType: String, Codable {
  case contract = "contract"
  case empty = ""
  case freelance = "freelance"
  case fullTime = "full_time"
  case other = "other"
  case partTime = "part_time"
}
```

What I want to do is, in SwiftUI, have a `Text` that shows for example `Full time` instead of the JSON attribute which would be `full_time`, of `Part time` instead of `part_time`. How can I do this?

EDIT: I have tried `Text(job.job_type)` an I'm getting an error:
`Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Jobs.JobType' conform to 'StringProtocol'. Did you mean to use '.rawValue'?`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some SwiftUI body code?

Comment: How did you try and what did not work for you?

Comment: thanks and sorry, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something crude and simple like this:

```
enum JobType: String, Codable {
  case contract = "contract"
  case empty = ""
  case freelance = "freelance"
  case fullTime = "full_time"
  case other = "other"
  case partTime = "part_time"
    
    func asString() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .contract: return "Contract"
        case .empty: return ""
        case .freelance: return "Freelance"
        case .fullTime: return "Full time"
        case .other: return "Other"
        case .partTime: return "Part time"
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Text(job.job_type.asString())
```

Comment: yes, this is definitely what I was looking for, but I was wondering if Swift would offer me something already built-in in the language, instead of having to do it by hand, but thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following computed property to your enum

```
var displayText: String {
    self.rawValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ").capitalized
}
```

and call it like

```
Text(job.job_type.displayText)
```